# Displaying plots in julia in notebook (using juliaBox)

Tags: plot, jupyter-notebook, julia

I want to display a plot in the julia language (using iJulia).
But is doesn't show the plot.
Here is a minimal working example of what I tried:

```
using Plots
function testplotting()
    x=[1,2,3,4]
    y1=[1,2,3,4]
    y2=[1,2,3,4]

    plt=plot(x,y)
    plot!(x,y2)
    return plt
end
plt=testplotting()
display(plt)
println("finished")`
```

But is doesn't show the plot..
Without the line where I add the extra line to plot the other array it works, but I want to plot multiple variables at the same time.
Can anyone explain why it doesn't display or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `plot!(plt, xlabel = "blabla")`.

`plot!` with a single argument implicitly modifies the "current" plot, which it gets by querying the current plot in global scope. Given that you are in a function scope, the global scope has no access to the plot you just created. Thus you need to specify which plot you want to modify.